# PHP - Converting a string into various date formats

Tags: php, string, date-format

I am new to PHP and cannot figure out the best method to convert two strings I have from URL params.

I would like to convert:
"August 2010" to ---> "2010-08-%"

and also:
"2010" to ---> "2010-%-%"

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function with `date`:

```
echo date('Y-m', strtotime('August 2010'));
```

Just adjust the format parameter to the `date` function to get the result in the format you are looking for. You might want to append the `%` part after convert the date format.

Comment: ah thank yee, i knew i was doing something wrong.
previously i used looping and the explode function to piece the string together!

Answer (score 2):

You can do those by learn to using these 2 following functions
strtotime http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
date http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php